# Write pre written bio page in real- time with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, bots

I'm creating a website and i want to add a bio page to it. I want the user to come onto the website and the bio page to type as if it was being typed up in real-time. My first thought was to get some form of a bot to do it as I have experience with automation anywhere but then I thought that maybe it can be done by javascript/jquery. What I'm looking for would be similar to how it looks if two people were editing a document on google drive. You would see the cursor move as the other user types. The bio will be pre-written and there would be a delay in what is typed to replicate somebody actually typing. Sorry if this has been asked before, ive tried searching the web but im not sure what to even search for.

Comment: Try searching for "javascript type writer effect". The results look promising. For the cursor I'd think about using a vertical line character (FWIW)

Comment: Great way for people to switch off from reading your bio. Do people really want to watch text appear before them, or read it as they wish?